# Unknown reference to Kendo Datasource

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-datasource

I am trying to use the KendoMVC Datasource component as shown in official page 
DataSource / Shared DataSource (http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/datasource/shared-datasource), but the following errors occur:

```
CSHTML File
@(Html.Kendo().DataSource<ConfiguracaoAgendaViewModel>()
        .Name("dsConfiguracoes")
        .Ajax(dataSource => dataSource
           .Read(read => read.Action("ListarConfiguracoes", "ConfiguracaoAgenda").Data("GetFiltrosGrid"))
           .ServerOperation(false)
        )
    )
```

Error   CS1061 :  'WidgetFactory' does not contain a definition for 'DataSource' and no extension method 'DataSource' accepting a first argument of type 'WidgetFactory' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

[Error PrintScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xszP0.png)

If anyone has a tip on how to solve this problem , I will be grateful!

Comment: Can you [edit] in at least the first two items as text instead of image? That would be easier to read and search for in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DataSource HtmlHelper is a relatively [new feature, introduced in Kendo UI version 2016.2.504](http://www.telerik.com/support/whats-new/aspnet-mvc/release-history/ui-for-asp-net-mvc-q2-2016). Please update the Kendo.Mvc.dll assembly (and subsequently the CSS and JavaScript files too).

Comment: I had not seen the availability of HtmlHelper for Kendo version I'm using. Thanks dimodi!